# Getting Eclipse Debugger to show string's underlying c_str() address

Tags: c++, eclipse, debugging, eclipse-cdt

I'm trying to better understand the CDT debug capabilities in Eclipse. I was exploring the memory window and wanted to look at the memory where a string was. The debugger has a breakpoint on the declaration of the string variable, so it hasn't even entered main() yet. I typed in the expression window the string name and invoked the c.str() function as shown in the image (Note the line that is commented out).

[image: expression won't evaulate]

Then I commented in the commented out line and it worked (see next image). My best guess is somehow the debugger gets a hint on the type for the expression and can render it.

My question is really two-fold, is that what's really going on? And if so, is there a way I can provide the type to the debugger in the expression window so that I don't have to modify my code? I tried the various cast options I could find but they didn't help. 
[image: expression evaluates correctly]

Comment: Expression evaluation in a debugger is difficult. Essentially it means to run code and pray that it doesn't have side effects. I have no idea what causes what you observed. However, a possible workaround/solution would be to **not** use an expression that calls a function. Instead, look up the class member that stores the pointer to the controlled sequence and use that in your expression in place of `c_str()`.

Comment: That's not too hard to do given than if I just type GREETING I can explore it and find that GREETING._M_dataplus._M_p has the pointer to the underlying string. I can then copy and paste that into the memory window without a problem. I'm creating a course module on the Eclipse debugger and wanted to understand this better. I think I'll just add your advice that one should try to avoid invoking functions in the expression or memory windows. If you promote your comment to a reply I'll mark it as the answer.

Comment: I'd rather not post the comment as an answer. It doesn't address the question as to what is going on here. As it stands I still don't know what's happening. With Eclipse being an open source project maybe someone who has contributed does know what's causing the expression evaluation to behave differently depending on the source code. Leaving the question unanswered seems to be more valuable than closing it with a not-quite-the-right-answer.